# Using XSSF to write xlsx using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Can someone give me an example of using `XSSF` to write `xlsx` files please?

**Edit:** aha...I did it myself the jars you'd need are-

dom4j
poi-3.8.jar
poi-ooxml-3.8.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8.jar
xbean.jar

Sample code -

```
package com.angrydog.impl;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class XSSFWorkBookWriter  {

    public void writeWorkBook(Vector table) throws WorkBookException {      

        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet();
        table=new Vector();
        table.add(new String("Howdy"));
        table.add(new java.sql.Date(2012,06,20));
        table.add(new Double(13.35D));
        table.add(new String("Fine"));
        table.add(new java.sql.Date(2012,06,20));
        table.add(new Double(13.38D));

        Iterator rows=table.iterator();
        Enumeration rowsOfVector=table.elements();
        int totalNoOfRows=table.size()/2;
        int currentRow=0;
        while (rows.hasNext () && currentRow<totalNoOfRows){
            XSSFRow row =  sheet.createRow(currentRow++);               

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                XSSFCell cell=row.createCell(i);
                Object val=rows.next();
                if( val instanceof String){
                    cell.setCellValue(val.toString());
                }
                else if(val instanceof Date){
                    cell.setCellValue((java.sql.Date)val);
                }
                else if(val instanceof Double){
                    cell.setCellValue((Double)val);
                }
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream outPutStream = null;
        try {
            outPutStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\\\"+"Try.xlsx");
            workBook.write(outPutStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (outPutStream != null) {
                try {
                    outPutStream.flush();
                    outPutStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XSSFWorkBookWriter bookWriter=new XSSFWorkBookWriter();
        try {
            bookWriter.writeWorkBook(new Vector());
        } catch (WorkBookException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check an example with comments on my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939375/how-to-resize-a-chart-using-xssf-apache-poi-3-8
I don't know if that is what you need.

Comment: You can look into samples / tutorials available at following link as well http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html Hope it helps.

Comment: I would use a more current version (3.17 at the time of writing) as many fixes and enhancement have been done since 3.8.