# How to resize POI XSSFChart

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

So i get chart from excel file (.xlsx) by this code.

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(10);
XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
XSSFChart chart = drawing.getCharts().get(0);
```

and i need to resize this chart like

```
chart.setHeight(100);
```

Comment: Thank you. I can fix it @SrikanthA

Comment: Please refer answer below, and mark as Answered if it answers your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CTMarker and XSSFDrawing, you shall resize with the coordinates as below.

```
XSSFDrawing draw= ((XSSFSheet)currentSheet).createDrawingPatriarch();
CTMarker chartEndCoords = CTMarker.Factory.newInstance();
chartEndCoords.setCol(column);
chartEndCoords.setColOff(0);
chartEndCoords.setRow(row);
chartEndCoords.setRowOff(0);
draw.getCTDrawing().getTwoCellAnchorArray(0).setTo(chartEndCoords);
```

Please refer here for detailed explanation- [Resize in POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939375/how-to-resize-a-chart-using-xssf-apache-poi-3-8)